# alias error when running javascript after compiling typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a project in which I am using typescript. in the project I am using aliases for imports,

example: `import { boomErrorHandler } from '#src/middleware';`

The problem is when I compile in code, since the imports continue to be made with aliases, and when I run it with node, it says that it cannot find the module

tsconfig.json
[image]

error when running js
[image]

package.json
[image]

after compilation
`const middleware_1 = require("#src/middleware");`

everything while I'm in development works because I run it with ts-node, but when I compile and try to run the .js file with node I get the error

I hope that after compilation I can run the resulting index.js file, without problems with paths and aliases